# Azure Log Analytics Workspace not discoverable in Power BI Premium workspace settings

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I want to integrate Power BI with Azure Log Analytics to enable administrators and Premium workspace owners to configure a Log Analytics connection to their Power BI subscription. I followed all [Microsoft documentation instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/log-analytics/desktop-log-analytics-configure#pre-requisites) that need to be done as a prerequisite and I enabled Azure Log Analytics connections for workspace administrators in the tenant settings, but the Azure Log Analytics workspace and its subscription and resource group are not discoverable (see picture below, all drop-down menus are greyed out). Am I overlooking something here (like, something that's not mentioned in the instructions but should be done as well)?

[image]